# How to replay web server logs stored in DB

Tags: sql-server, iis

We have a large, complex SSAS app.  We keep extensive logs in a database containing each request, it's variables (GET/POST), session keys etc.

We would like to replay these logs for stress testing of the app.  The idea is to take a DB backup of the production server during a maintenance window, reboot the web servers, capture a couple of days of traffic, restore the DB to a test server and replay the logs files on the test server.

Ideally we would be able to ramp up the request speed, ie, run at double-time.  This sort of testing would also be useful for some automated regression testing.

I could write something myself to do this, but it seems like a problem that has been solved before.

JMeter does not appear to be suitable for this, what other tools are there?

Answer (score 0):

Dave - Couple of thoughts below.  You note IIS as your web server so:

Web Capacity Analysis Tool (WCAT) is [downloadable here](http://www.iis.net/community/default.aspx?tabid=34&g=6&i=1466).

For a bit more background on WCAT, have a look at [Mike Volodarsky's blog entry](http://mvolo.com/blogs/serverside/archive/2008/01/24/Updated-WCAT-6.3-released.aspx)

There may be something more recent on codeplex.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The only way I can see WCAT being able to do this would be to create a scenario file from the logs? This scenario file would probably contain a million or so scenarios. I'm looking for a tool that I can point at a database table and have to re-run the requests in that table.